# Merge/sum a list of dicts based on a certain key/value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts as shown below.

```
[
    {"value1": 53, "day": "Thu, 07 May 2015", "value2": 70, "type_of": "foo"},
    {"value1": 17, "day": "Thu, 07 May 2015", "value2": 12, "type_of": "foo"},
    {"value1": 21, "day": "Thu, 12 May 2013", "value2": 40, "type_of": "foo"}
]
```

Now I'm trying to combine the dicts that have the same value for the `"day"` key in a way that sums the `"value1"`/`"value2"` keys and leaves the `"type_of"` alone.

Below is my intended result:

```
[
    {"value1": 70, "day": "Thu, 07 May 2015", "value2": 82, "type_of": "foo"},
    {"value1": 21, "day": "Thu, 12 May 2013", "value2": 40, "type_of": "foo"}
]
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: What if they have the same day value but different type_of values? Which one do you keep?

Comment: @Farhan.K We can assume type_of is always "foo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More compact solution with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

# data array in df 

res = defaultdict (lambda : {"value1": 0, "value2": 0, "day": "", "type_of": "foo"})

for x in df:
    res[x["day"]]["value1"] += x["value1"]
    res[x["day"]]["value2"] += x["value2"]
    res[x["day"]]["day"] = x["day"]
    res[x["day"]]["type_of"] = x["type_of"]


print (res)
```

Comment: This solution gives me the following error:  

TypeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @DidahDrieghe Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to use pandas? 
It is very handy and makes your life much easier:

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = [{"value1": 53, "day": "Thu, 07 May 2015", "value2": 70, "type_of": "foo"},
     {"value1": 17, "day": "Thu, 07 May 2015","value2": 12,"type_of" : "foo"},
     {"value1": 21, "day": "Thu, 12 May 2013", "value2": 40, "type_of": "foo"}]


# Create a "table" with keys as column names and set as index the pair (day, type_of)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1).set_index(['day', 'type_of'])

# Here you sum values with same day and type_of. This is already what you are
# looking for    
out_df = df1.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()
# This last bit is to convert back to dictionary, although I would suggest to 
# use pandas dataframes rather than lists of dictionaries
out_dict = out_df.reset_index().to_dict(orient = 'record')

# out = [{'day': 'Thu, 07 May 2015', 'value1': 70L, 'value2': 82L},
#      {'day': 'Thu, 12 May 2013', 'value1': 21L, 'value2': 40L}]
```

Comment: This works - now to figure out how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it works. I have added some comments to the code to make it more explicit. Hope it clarifies!

Comment: Also, i have changed the computation of the sum so it would work even if you had more types for the same day

Comment: If the answer was helpful you might also consider upvoting :)

Comment: I upvoted but don't have enough reputation for the vote to show. Thanks for the explanation, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I build a little code similar that one you need, hope it will help you to finish your task.

```
list_dicts = [
    {"value1": 53, "day": "Thu, 07 May 2015", "value2": 70, "type_of": "foo",},
    {"value1": 17, "day": "Thu, 07 May 2015","value2": 12,"type_of": "foo"},
    {"value1": 21, "day": "Thu, 12 May 2013", "value2": 40, "type_of": "foo"}
]

dicts_by_day = {}

for ldict in list_dicts:
    if ldict["day"] in dicts_by_day:
        dicts_by_day[ldict["day"]].append(ldict)
    else:
        dicts_by_day[ldict["day"]] = [ldict]

for day, values in dicts_by_day.items():
    print(day,values)
```

In this last iteration you can make the operation that you need for each day's group.

Try to edit your question (your "list_dicts" is not correctly written)